# tshark how to count the number of returned packets

Tags: wireless-networking, pcap, tshark

I am using tshark and i need to findout how many of my 10,0000 packets contain a `HTTP URI`

Therefore, i have written the line of code that goes as followes:

```
tshark -r tsharklab.pcap -Y "http.request.uri"
```

However, when it is run, it provides all of them without re-formatiing the packet number.

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMKWS.png)

What i need to achieve is calculating the number of returned packets after the filter is compleate.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just count them via wc -l

```
tshark -r tsharklab.pcap -Y "http.request.uri" |wc -l
```